# Настройка url yii2

Tags: yii2, роутинг

Я использую роутинг в Yii2. Задача стоит в том, что бы все страницы вида

```
/page-about
/page-news
/page-temp
```

обрабатывало действие контролера. Пробовал писать так:

```
'/page-<pref:\w+>/' => 'main/static-page'
```

но оно не работает. Контролер и действие в нем есть, но выдает 404.
Помогите составить правильный роутинг

Answer (score 1):

Как только написал вопрос, сразу сам увидел ошибку

```
'/page-<pref:\w+>' => 'main/static-page'
```

Был лишний слеш